# Sublime text 3: what is the sublime text package needs to be installed to open folder dialog from the code?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have the html tag like this

```
<img src="" >
```

and if i want to supply the path to this, i just needed to hardcode my path. I don't know how can raise folder dialog popup from my html code to lookup the exact path and select the same. Do i have any shortcut to do this or any package needs to be installed?

Comment: You can install a plugin to autocomplete the path as you type it, but none will open a file picker dialog. Sublime doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file you want to supply the path to in Sublime Text.
Control click (right click) the file body and choose `Copy File Path`.
Paste the value in the `src=""` attribute. (You may want to change it from an absolute link to a relative link)

Comment: Thanks @jwpfox. We don't have any package to directly open the folder window to choose the file path?

Comment: I don't know of any and @MatDMo (who is truly a genius on ST) says their isn't so it seems no is the answer.